# Python - PyQt QInputDialog.getItem Cancel button problem with app drops

Tags: python, pyqt, runtime-error

After calling QInputDialog.getItem if I select the option and press OK everything works. The problem occurs if I press Cancel the program crashes with this error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

After debug this error is that I am not loading data into variables:

```
(<class 'UnboundLocalError'>, UnboundLocalError("local variable 'link' referenced before assignment"), <traceback object at 0x000001BC8209DE00>)
```

**How to treat this so that after pressing Cancel the program continues without crashing?**

```
query = "SELECT name FROM datasets"
datasets = cur.execute(query).fetchall()
items = ()
for dataset in datasets:
   items += dataset
item, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "select input dialog", "list of languages", items, 0, False)
if ok and item:
   query = "SELECT name, file FROM datasets"
   datasets = cur.execute(query).fetchall()
   for dataset in datasets:
      if dataset[0] == item:
         link = dataset[1]
         dataset_name = "Meno datasetu: " + str(dataset[0].split("-")[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize link before accessing it

```
link = None
item, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "select input dialog", "list of languages", items, 0, False)
if ok and item:
  ...
```